# Is checking without a on boot check enough after clicking a malicious link in a mail?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, virus, anti-virus

After quite a few years it seems like I now myself fell over a malicious mail. 
Now my question is if what I have scannerwise active and also what I did is good enough to feel save again?

**The Mail itself:**

The mail was a reminder and contained a link where I got an upgrade for a book (upgrade from the standard to a deluxe edition of the book) for a discount. Just 2 weeks earlier I got the normal discount mail from the books producer. Just after clicking the link (normally I double check the target locations....first time I didn't :/ ) I saw taht teh site that is trying to load is not the expected one (not the one of the online shop). I closed my browser (google chrome), closed all programs and started a quick scan from AD aware and then the full AV scan (details below).

Have to admit that that mail was pretty good. As that upgrade and the book are very specific (its a table top gaming rulebook) they must have had very specific data there to create that mail.

I immediately contacted the books producer and asked them there and got told that they sent me the original mail but not this reminder mail.

Link content (http: replaced by http__ to avoid accidental clicks):

> http__//go.sparkpostmail.com/f/a/B1uKVS2MjvAolIhaHhpikw~~/AACncAA~/RgRZFLWLP0EIAWuZI94tuR8XWAQAAAAAWQdkZWZhdWx0QgoABQuCM1dWcjJbUg9ldDI0MDVAeWFob28uZGUJUQQAAAAARD9odHRwOi8vd3d3LmRyaXZldGhydXJwZy5jb20vcHJvZHVjdC8xODAzODMvJmRpc2NvdW50PTkxYzFlYTlhMzBHAnt9

The above link content was hidden behind a link to the web shop where one can order the book for the discount. Only thing being the discount url itself was silghtly malformed and only led to teh non discounted book.

**The website:**

From what I saw on google the website is lying as a subsite on some hosting providers site (didn't dare to go onto the site of the provider though after this experience).  From what I saw in chrome it was still loading and didn't finish loading when I closed chrome.

**My system:**

I'm using windows 10 and avast as virus scanner. Additionally I have ad aware installed since some time (all up to date).

**What did I do?:**

I immediately closed google chrome and most other applications I had running and ran AD-aware quick scan (no result). 
After that I ran a complete scan (not a boot scan) over night with avast. 
2 files in app data were not openable (due to other processes) and I closed all other applications like skype that were still running and manually let avast scan the folder and also nothing there. Then scanned the user folders with ad-aware for the same result.

When I tried to start google chrome now I got an error message (memory error) and immediately started an avast scan of the program folders (ad-aware is to follow).

If nothing comes out I plan to restart the computer and then make a full ad-aware scan of my system drive. Aside from that then back to normal computer usage.

I asked the book producer if that mail was real or fake. After getting the answer "very probably fake" I asked them if they want to have that mail forwarded to them else I will delete it immediately (from what I read some IT
departments in companies want such mails forwarded, others not thus asked there).

**The question**

Is that enough? Or should I also run the on boot check or do anything else there?

Comment: If you have the link still it could be checked for its 'payload'.  I wouldn't post it clicksble ( add spaces to it to prevent accidental clicks)  but the quickest way to answer your question is to see what its trying to do ( in a controlled sandbox by a knowledgeable person)

Comment: @Argonauts I updated the question with the link included (replaced http: by http__ ).

Comment: I wont be able to safely check until tomorrow (+8 hrs from now) but will do so if no else has responded by then.

Comment: https://www.virustotal.com/en/url/f0f40c5a19478a3c68b8f009811b3c74f4d2e8a4c70d4cd94e76977e1296cff6/analysis/1463216576/

Comment: Its clean. See prev comment link to an online scanner. I don't get why chrome is crashing now though. Thats the part of the question that led me to believe there was an issue ( beyond just good prudent checking on your part)  theories on that?

Comment: Tnx. it worked again after rebooting. I know that that happens seldomly with chrome but the timing was........bad^^ (I had it thrice in 5 years of chrome usage so far mostly when I had computers run for over 24 hours nonstop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you provided looks like a typical email click tracking redirect link. The site that the url first goes to tracks the hit then redirects to the correct url.

This can be verified by using a redirect checking tool such as [Redirect Checker](http://www.redirect-checker.org/). In your case, there is one redirect which would take you to:

http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/180383/&discount=91c1ea9a30

a product page selling a PDF of "A Call to Arms: Star Fleet, Book One, Revision Two, Deluxe Edition". The site itself appears to be devoted to the sale of RPG related paraphernalia.

Further investigation shows that sparkpostmail.com is probably owned by [Sparkpost](https://www.sparkpost.com/), a bulk marketing email provider. (`whois` records show that sparkpostmail.com and sparkpost.com are registered under the same person.)

Comment: Yepp drivethru is the onlnie web shop. So just a tracking redirect and nothing where something gets downloaded and then it redirects to the correct url to avoid getting seem for what it is? lol the book producer then doesnt know some features about the sites they use and send mails from (they said that drivethru and wargaming don't let them use outside links and thus the mail can't be a real one).

Comment: @Thomas It's not so much that they're hiding the final destination (though that is a side effect), just that this is a means of tracking email link clicks. I find there's a certain kind of person who completely misunderstands how something works but insists on telling you (their own, wrong interpretation of) how it works anyway. Your book producer may be such a person.

Comment: Yepp. Taht is what I meant. Hoenstly I had hoped for just that (as sending out a fake upgrade link was just would have meant that a possible hacker had WAY more personal infos about me than I would like...aka knowing that I had the book,... and as its not a mainstream book the implications would have been bad). for my comment above: I had feared that it was a link where it downloads malware and then sends you to the correct site so that it does look save/normal and the non malware illusion stays longer. Glad it was not that. Tnx a lot!
Will accept when I get home.